# How to make a url page like www.example.com:5362 (like cpanel)

Tags: web-deployment, web-hosting

Thank you for reading. Is that anyone knows how to make url like www.example.com:3663

I saw that cpanel urls are using this method. It loads control panel of their hosting. Can I create something like that url and get my own page onto it?

Answer (score 0):

The format of this URL is:

```
example.com:<port-number>
```

So the way to achieve this is by using ports on the server. For example, HTTP requests typically hit port 80, and HTTPS (SSL) requests hit port 443.

cpanel uses this method to redirect requests for the admin control panel to a different area - you can recreate this by configuring your webserver (typically Apache or Nginx) but this is not normally done for regular simple web pages.